# Use own Material Theme in Storybook for Angular App

Tags: colors, angular-material, themes, storybook

is it possible to use our own Angular Material Theme in the Storybook ? Unfortunately our components in the storybook are not styled. Primarily it's about colors.  We would like to put on our themes.scss in the storybook.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

guys,
the easiest way to transfer your styles to storybook within a library is to create a new project called "storybook". This project has to be the first in Angular.json. Then you just copy your styles into the styles.scss and you can use your theme in the storybook.

Comment: Could you explain more ?

Comment: We work with an Angular Library and we only add a Project with the name storybook. 

 ng g application storybook. We don't do nothing more and it works

Comment: Not sure if that's the way storybook is supposed to be implemented. And what if I have an angular workspace with multiple apps (projects), and libraries of components that should look different depending on the app they are used in (Each app has its own theme)?